# Why is my for loop not producing an output?

Tags: c++

My program should perform a calculation to get the sum of every number in the range specified with startVal and endVal. I've looked at other somewhat similar questions, but I haven't pulled much from them. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong in the for loop, so I can fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main() {
    //Declare variables
    int startVal;
    int endVal;
    int newVal;
    int sum;

    cout << "Enter starting value for loop (1 - 500): ";
        cin >> startVal;
    while (startVal<=1 || startVal>=500) {
        cout << "Invalid starting value.\n";
    }

    while(startVal>=1 && startVal<=500) {
            cout << "Enter ending value for loop (" << startVal+1 << " - 1000): ";
            cin >> endVal;

            if(endVal<startVal+1 || endVal>1000) {
                cout << "Invalid ending value.\n";
            }

        }

    for(startVal=newVal; newVal==endVal; ++newVal) {
                sum = newVal+1;
            }

    cout << "The sum of the integers from " << startVal << " through " << endVal << " is " << sum << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really look at `for(startVal=newVal; newVal==endVal; ++newVal)`.  Is the condition true?

Comment: You could step through the code in your debugger to understand why the loop isn't correct.

Comment: Check your closures. It looks to me that `while(startVal>=1 && startVal<=500)` will always be true.

Comment: @NathanOliver What do you mean by condition? I haven't used a boolean, and I'm not sure what the correct test would be in my for loop.

Comment: The loop body will execute only as long as `newVal==endVal` is _true_. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Blastfurnace I meant that as until it's equal to endVal, but I've since fixed it to as long as it's less than or equal to it.

Comment: The code runs fine up until the for loop. Once I input an end value, it just asks me for an end value again, without performing the calculation or outputting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `for` loop to this (as noted by comments):

```
sum = 0;
for( newVal=startVal; newVal<=endVal; ++newVal ) {
  sum += newVal;
}
```

As for the second `while()` loop add some `break` condition. E.g.:

```
if( (endVal<startVal+1) || (endVal>1000) ) {
  cout << "Invalid ending value.\n";
}else{
  break;
}
```

Comment: The first two loops work and I'm able to enter all the values, but the for loop appears not to run, as it just asks me for an end value again once I input it.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've saved me. May I ask, why exactly was not including the break a problem?

Comment: Well, the second `while()` loop never ended. There is only check of `startVal` and the value is not changed, so if it is OK, the loop is endless. Still asking for end value.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you, sometimes I'm clueless as to what my program is doing since this is my first time learning a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, there are 2 problems with your for loop.  The three parts of the loop declaration are:
1. Variable declaration :  yours is wrong 
2.  condition : yours in wrong 
3.  Increment : this is fine.